# Sourcetree not refreshing view

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

The view within sourcetree has to be manually updated by hitting F5 as of version 3.3.6.3829. I attempted to raise this as a bug on https://jira.atlassian.com/, but the form doesn't give me a correct option for version with 3.2 being the most up to date version available. If someone can point me to the correct place to raise this bug, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This happened to me and the only way was to reinstall SourceTree 3.2.1, at least until the refresh bug gets fixed by Atlassian.  I can't complain, it's a great tool and it's free, but this was annoying.  I'm always a little apprehensive upgrading software I make, much less someone else's!

Here is the download page you can install older versions, I suggest 3.2.1, which works great!  https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/download-archives

Following up: I'm on Windows and at least in my instance to get it to work all I did was:

1. Close SourceTree
2. Download 3.2.1 from the link above
3. Run the installer

Then I opened SourceTree and it reverted the version back by itself and I haven't had any issues since. I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I attempted to downgrade, but am having issues even uninstalling the application. For some reason it doesn't even run the uninstaller even though I have local admin rights. I have a feeling that there is something conflicting between the uninstaller and the security features from my workplace. For now I am just hoping for an update to fix the issue.

Comment: @dmoore1181 I'm on Windows and at least in my instance to get it to work, all I did was close SourceTree, then I downloaded 3.2.1 from the link above, then I ran the installer.  Then I opened SourceTree and it reverted the version back, haven't had any issues since.  i hope this helps, but of course this might not work in your case but best of luck!

Comment: Yes, same issue and downgrading to Windows version 3.3.4 (28 Oct '19) solved that for me.

Comment: At the risk of being fussy, 3.2.6 is the Windows version (3.2.1 is a Mac release) but downgrading to 3.2.6 (on Windows) worked for me too.

Comment: Still present in 3.3.7.

Answer (score -1):

The installer may be at fault. I found that my Source Tree short cuts didn't point to the correct "start in" folder. I thought correcting that has fixed the refresh problem, but I was wrong.